# about UIAlert jumps to one xib

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton, uialertview

I have some three xib files, a b  c
there is a button on b,and it will show an alert when click it,the code is

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
 initWithTitle:@"Warning"
 message:@"You will jump to a when you click 'Yes,Go',or click 'No,I am not' for exit" 
 delegate:nil 
 cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes,Go"
     cancelButtonTitle:@"No,I am not" 
 otherButtonTitles:nil];
 [alert show];
 [alert release];
```

as its description, I want to jump to the a when I click the 'Yes,Go',this app will be closed if I click  'No,I am not'

So what should do?

Thanks

Comment: why are you writing cancelButtonTitle twice?

Answer (score 4):

you can handle the event in alert view delegate

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

here check for button index and do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

First of write your UIAlertView like below,

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"You will jump to a when you click 'Yes,Go',or click 'No,I am not' for exit" 
                          delegate:self 
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes,Go"
                          otherButtonTitles:@"No,I am not" 
                          ,nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
```

then you can handle which button is tapped by user as below code:

```
 -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{   
    if(buttonIndex ==0)
    {
        //handle it for "Yes,Go"
    }

    else if (buttonIndex ==1)
    {
        //handle it for "No,I am not"
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We are missing a lot of details here to answer this question I think. What is the structure of your program? How do you show the xib files etc.

Comment: i mean i just want to the function like that ,if i click yes,it will jump to a xib file,if i click no ,the app will be closed ,so ... thanks